# Typescript: combining keyof with conditional plus generic subtype

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-generics

Following @jcalz, I rewrote this question.

See the working example here:
[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAYwNghgzlAEBiBLApmAJgHgCoD5YG9hZYQB7AOygBcAnAVxCtJoAoAHOgIzERFgDcIYOsgBcsLAEoCAX2BzQkGLACSVZAFsCRWInKIqSVGigsAZinRRx%20WAG0ACrvKwA1sgCepM7CoALRCgAXQB%20cQhyD1gZaUJiYgB5TgArZEYAOmRyWhRTC2MoSXSzZgBRCBA-Fh142BY7NhpSNgAaASEg6QBePBYWf0CGprZYaDdPb18A4NG4CI9u2HJkAHcESzQWQTBJSRrYSQBuHTk5cGg4eFJSWGQAD3VyE1V1LTjYTggaAEYAQnEjOgMNQaHoAOY4Y7ET40ABM-3Wxgw5DoGk4yBokJ0bDAyGgyBUYPIzGQAFlkLAurAAETU446PQGFixfYDKDpRmGDamd61GHfcTUkqkaktfbQr6w8QAFlhYtqMSh0XkwFAFGosGFlKWqwQ12Zx2FHP0VANasopFx6TApDB5mu6X56W2IiOsAA9O6acLqUA)

I want to securely type the `initFields` method below. So that

a) Only Fields are accepted as `prop` (and e.g. the `pleaseIgnoreMe` property is not allowed).

b) Only the type that the Field contains is allowed as `val`. E.g. only string is allowed for bar1

```
class Field<T> {
  constructor(public value: T) {}
}

class Item {
  initFields(fields: { [P in keyof this]?: any }) {
    Object.entries(fields).forEach(
      ([prop, val]) => ((this[prop as keyof this] as any) = new Field(val))
    );
  }
}
class Foo extends Item {
  bar1!: Field<string>;
  bar2!: Field<number>;
  pleaseIgnoreMe = "";

  init() {
    this.initFields({
      bar1: "foo",
      bar2: 42,
    });
  }
}

const foo = new Foo();
foo.init();
console.log(foo.bar1.value); // "foo"
```

Comment: Please consider modifying the code in this question so as to constitute a [mcve] which, when dropped into a standalone IDE like The TypeScript Playground [(link to code)](https://tsplay.dev/wOaKym), clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  (e.g., you should either define `Field` or remove references to it; and resolve unrelated errors like uninitialized properties)  This will allow those who want to help you to immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  And it will make it so that any answer you get is testable against a well-defined use case.

Comment: Dear @jcalz, I rewrote the whole thing. I hope it is better understandable now? Thank you for looking into it.

Comment: Does something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/weeAKw) work for you?  Unfortunately `this` types don't really have the ability to represent the constraints you want, and most attempts I've been using to try to express this correctly run afoul of circularity detection warnings in the compiler.  The code above is the closest I could get.

Comment: Interesting approach. Thank you very much. And indeed, this case is really hard to type correctly.